# Override ConfigurationProperties Of Library from Application

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties

I've created a ConfigurationProperties in my base-library:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "base.props")
public class DemoProperties {
    private String host;
    private String realm;
}
```

Then I build my library and handled a jar file and imported to an application.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sha</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-library</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I try to set properties from spring-boot application via application.properties:

```
base.props.host=Test
base.props.realm=Test
```

but these aren't seen by library.and Intellij says "Cannot resolve configuration property..."

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was `"application.properties"` on library. Changed the name to `"application-x.properties"` and solved.